# Segue misunderstanding

Tags: ios, swift, segue, unwind-segue

I am little confused with the way that segue is working in my app.

I have `TabBarController` and my `ViewController` inside it is embedded in `NavigationController`.

[image]

I added identifier to segue "`mySegue`". So when i perform some action inside my `ViewController` I run

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: self)
```

So segue is performed but I have some things that I don't understand.

1. View is presented without tab bar and navigation bar. Why? I thought that they should be visible by default.
2. I want segue to be animated - so view will be presented from right to left and also I will be able to unwind it (simply go back by swiping). But swipe back is not working and view is presented from bottom to top. Why is it?

Comment: WRT the Nav Bar, click on your segue and in attribute inspector make sure the type is set to Push, Not Modal.

Comment: I tried to set it to push and replace with no luck

Comment: If your Segue *is* set to `(Show e.g push)`, and you *do* have your storyboard configured as shown, and you call `performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: self)` but it does ***not*** push the next ViewController onto the navigation stack? Then you are looking the wrong thing. Take a step back, delete any existing segues or connections, and then re-implement them.

Comment: @DonMag it helped! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was not the first time when I meet this problem - I need to point where the problem was. Maybe it will help others when it seems that everything in segue is made right way but it is not working the way it should.

In my case - it was because segue was created in interface builder by dragging not from the ViewController's yellow circle to second ViewController. Segue was created from one of subviews or even TableView / TableViewCell inside ViewController. So in that case it wasn't creating segue in NavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the segue's type to Push - that way the navigagtion controller will issue the hierarchy and it will actually get pushed to its stack, hence the name.

Comment: You need to use `show`. A navigation controller pushes the new view controller onto its navigation stack when `show` is used. Check: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want your segue to transits horizontally,  you need to use (Show e.g push) for the segue, like this. It has swipe back by default

[image: [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/]

Comment: @Fangming ... "swipe back" *is* default behavior for Navigation Controller

Comment: @moonvader Updated